# ImageView push button off the screen

Tags: android, imageview

I have a problem with scaling ImageView. Picture is scaled, but i think it can't see the button below, that's why it's still to big and push the button off the screen. I tried

```
android:layout_above="@id/q">
```

but it doesn't work because the declaration of button is below the imageview.

here's my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical">


    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logoimage"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/logoduuuze_03"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart">
    </ImageView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/q"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/logoimage"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/logoimage"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/logoimage">



    </Button>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

I just would like to have imageview and button on the screen, but just a little bit smaller.
How to make button "visible" for imageview? Or maby there's another way?

I would be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change this

```
android:layout_below="@id/logoimage"
```

to

```
android:layout_below="@+id/logoimage"
```

for in Button.

also

```
android:layout_above="@id/q"
```

to

```
android:layout_above="@+id/q"
```

Check this..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logoimage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
</ImageView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/q"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/logoimage"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="button" >
</Button>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @user3235612 Now check this.

Comment: it worked when i deleted android:layout_below="@+id/logoimage"  and used android:layout_above="@+id/q". Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Change :

```
        android:id="@+id/logoimage"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

to

```
        android:id="@+id/logoimage"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

Check what
`android:layout_alignBottom` does,

Makes the bottom edge of this view match the bottom edge of the given anchor view ID